# position matplotlib label above the subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas, legend, prettyplotlib

right now by default matplotlib legend is in the top right of all my subplots (say a group of 3 horizontally by 3 vertically).

However the legend is obscuring some of the trend line in some cases, so I would like to position the legend just above the subplot itself, is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

The location of the legend is specified using the `loc` argument to [`legend`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.legend). You can try using the `'best'` option and see if it avoids the lines. If you want to place the legend box outside your plot area, you can have a look at the technique described in the [legend guide](http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html#legend-location).

Here is a three-by-three grid of subplots with one legend top right above the plots:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
for i in range(9):
    plt.subplot(3, 3, i+1)
    plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1])
plt.subplot(3, 3, 3)
plt.legend(['test'], bbox_to_anchor=(0, 1, 1, 0.5), mode='expand')
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Comment: after looking in the legend guide, I can't see any technique where the result is a legend on top of the subplot (and not inside it blocking the trend line). Can you point me to an example of the output and code?

Comment: Look at the example under ["Legend Location"](http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html#legend-location). It features subplots and a legend outside the subplot region.

Comment: Thanks @chthonicdaemon - where can I learn more about "bbox_to_anchor" which seems to be responsible for both 1) the positioning of the legend above the subplot and 2) the positioning of the text so it is off centre to the left or aligned to centre (when it's above the subplot).

Comment: I.e. of the four parameters to "plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0., 1.02, 1., .102), loc=3,ncol=2, mode="expand", borderaxespad=0.)" is it 0. = left 1.02 = top right etc?

Comment: It's (x, y) of the bottom left corner or (x, y, x, y) for bottom left, top right.

Comment: Thanks for the output! Is there any way of making the text "TEST" centred in the middle of it's position at the top of the subplot? I've tried various alignments like "centre right" "centre left" but all are slightly off centre to the left or right.

Comment: I think you should ask that as a new question. Has my answer helped?